# I have a question that asks to reverse of an array using MIPS assembly language using MARS 4.5 simulator

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I used this code with this data segement and wanted to reverse a 4 element in the array and ofcourse I can change it so dont worry about that.

```
    .data
array:  .word 1 2 3 5
tab:    .asciiz "\t"
    .text
    .globl main
main:
    li $t0, 4   # $t0 is loop counter
    la $t2, array 
while:
    beq $t0, $zero, exit   # loop condition :: i!=0;
    lw $t1, 16($t2)
    
    li $v0,1
    move $a0, $t1
    syscall
    # print space
    li $v0, 4 
    la $a0, tab
    syscall
    # loop increments :: i--, array--
    addi $t0, $t0, -1  #i--
    addi $t2, $t2, -4  #array--
    j while
 
exit:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

and the output is:

```
543516788   5   3   2   
-- program is finished running --
```

what am I doing wrong?
I just want to know why it shows 543516788 5 3 2 instead of 5 3 2 1
and thanks in advance

Comment: Step through the code one instruction at a time. Pay attention to what happens at the `lw $t1, 16($t2)`.

Comment: Try debugging the code.

Comment: Is the goal to print the array in reverse or to actually reverse it (change the memory locations)?